# Chips and Salsa using header file

Tags: c++

Revise Programming Challenge 3 to use an array of Product objects instad of two parallel arrays. The Product class will need member variables to hold a product name and a quantity.

Challenge 3: Write a program that lets a maker of chips and salsa keep track of their sales for five different types of salsa they produce: mild, medium, sweet, hot, and zesty. It should use two parallel five-element arrays: an array of strings that holds five salsa names and an array of integers that holds the number of jars sold during the past month for each salsa type. The salsa names should be stored using an initialization list at the time the name array is created. The program should prompt the user to enter the number of jars sold for each type. One this sales data has been entered, the program should produce a report that displays sales for each salsa type, total sales, and the names of the highest selling and lowest selling products.

I did Challenge 3, code [here](http://pastebin.com/KNjkNVA4).

After much trying, I can't seem to get said program to work. I've commented the errors, and what they are. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#ifndef SALSA_H
#define SALSA_H

class Salsa 
{
private:
    void getTotal(); 
    void getHigh();
    void getLow();
    int count;
    int total;
    int high;
    int low;
    int flavor;
public:
    void getSold();
};
#endif

#include "Salsa.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void Salsa::getSold()
{
    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        cout << "Jar sold last month of ";
        cout << count + 1;
        cin >> flavor[count]; //Get error saying subscript array or pointer type

        while (flavor[count] <= 0) // Get error saying subscript array or pointer type
            cout << "Jars sold must be greater than or equal to 0.";
        cout << "Re-enter jars sold for last month ";
        cin >> flavor[count];
        cout << endl;

    }
}

Salsa::getTotal();
Salsa::getHigh();
Salsa::getLow();
}

void Salsa::getTotal() 

        total = 0; 

    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++) 
        total += flavor[count];

    cout << "Total Sales: " << total << endl;
}

void Salsa::getHigh() 
{
    highest = flavor[0];
    int index = 1;

    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++)
        if (flavor[count] > highest)
        {
        highest = flavor[count];
        index = count + 1;
        }

    cout << "High Seller: " << flavor << endl;
}

void Salsa::getLow() 
{
    lowest = flavor[0];
    int index = 1;

    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++)
        if (flavor[count] < lowest)
        {
        lowest = flavor[count];
        index = count + 1;
        }

    cout << "Low Seller: " << flavor << endl;
}

#include "Salsa.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    const int SALS_FLAV = 5; 
    string flavor[SALS_FLAV] = { "mild", "medium", "sweet", "hot", "zesty"          };

    Salsa sold;

    for (int index = 0; index < SALS_FLAV; index++)
        getSold(flavor[SALS_FLAV]); // Get error saying 'getSold' identifier not found

        sold.getSold();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inside `Salsa` `flavor` is an integer value not an array.

Comment: Could you please re-formulate your question so it doesn't sound so much as your homework assignment? To answer your question, we don't have to know anything about the "Challenge 3" :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek Sorry, I'll edit the main post with that question too. It's not homework, but I'm just going over a C++ book a friend of mine let me borrow, and trying to do the programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. The following code may do what you want.

You should study it and try to improve it. One such improvement could be the use of `std::vector` as opposed to arrays. This will mean you can avoid manual memory management (new/delete) and therefore achieve the ideal of not having to define a destructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Salsa
{
public:
    Salsa(string* flavours, int num_flavours);
    ~Salsa();
    void getSold();

private:
    void getTotal();
    void getHigh();
    void getLow();
    string* flavours_;
    int num_flavours_;
    int* sold_count_;
};

Salsa::Salsa(string* flavours, int num_flavours)
{
    num_flavours_ = num_flavours;
    flavours_ = new string[num_flavours_];
    sold_count_ = new int[num_flavours_];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_flavours_; i++)
    {
        flavours_[i] = flavours[i];
    }
}

Salsa::~Salsa()
{
    delete[] flavours_;
    delete[] sold_count_;
}

void Salsa::getSold()
{
    int count;
    int num;
    for (count = 0; count < num_flavours_; count++)
    {
        cout << "Jar sold last month of " << flavours_[count] << " ";

        cin >> num;

        while(num <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Jars sold must be greater than or equal to 0." << endl;
            cout << "Re-enter jars sold for last month " << endl;
            cin >> num;
        }

        sold_count_[count] = num;
    }

    getTotal();
    getHigh();
    getLow();
}

void Salsa::getTotal() 
{
    int count;
    int total = 0; 

    for (count = 0; count < num_flavours_; count++) 
        total += sold_count_[count];

    cout << "Total Sales: " << total << endl;
}

void Salsa::getHigh() 
{
    int count;
    int highest = sold_count_[0];
    int index = 0;

    for (count = 0; count < num_flavours_; count++)
    {
        if (sold_count_[count] > highest)
        {
            highest = sold_count_[count];
            index = count;
        }
    }

    cout << "High Seller: " << flavours_[index] << endl;
}

void Salsa::getLow() 
{
    int count;
    int lowest = sold_count_[0];
    int index = 0;

    for (count = 0; count < num_flavours_; count++)
    {
        if (sold_count_[count] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = sold_count_[count];
            index = count;
        }
    }

    cout << "Low Seller: " << flavours_[index] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int SALS_FLAV = 5; 
    string flavor[SALS_FLAV] = { "mild", "medium", "sweet", "hot", "zesty" };

    Salsa sold(flavor, SALS_FLAV);

    sold.getSold();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've heard about vectors before, but with the book I'm using, they don't talk about them until Chapter 10, and I'm on Chapter 8... But, from what I've read about them online, it does seem like they're better than arrays, but I can't use them yet. Thank you for helping me though, using your code as a base I managed to get mine working.